# Could not load source 'dart:_http/http_impl.dart': <source not available>

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

My flutter app is crashing and showing this error "Could not load source 'dart:_http/http_impl.dart': ."
My pub file

```
name: name_here description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org. version: 1.0.0+1

environment:   sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:   flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  banner: ^0.1.3   cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2  
    # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.   # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.   cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2   sqflite: any   flutter_rating: ^0.0.2   flutter_firebase_ui: ^0.0.12  

dev_dependencies:   flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter. flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is   # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in   # the material Icons class.   uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:   # assets:   #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg   #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see   # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
# https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
# in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a   # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a   # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For   # example:   # fonts:   #   - family: Schyler   #     fonts:   #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf   #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf   #         style: italic   #   - family: Trajan Pro   #     fonts:   #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf   #  
- asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf   #         weight: 700   #   # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,   # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: Don't import files that start with `_...`

Comment: where is the problem?

Comment: Not in the part you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Add `http` to dependencies like

```
dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.0
```

and then run `flutter packages get` and import it like

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
```

Comment: in my project i don't using 'dart:_http/http_impl.dart' package. So where should i import this?

Comment: Hard to tell. Where does the error come from? Is there a strack trace printed with the error message?

Comment: i don't get any error message i dont no why and how to view error ,because i am new in flutter

Comment: Where did you get "Could not load source 'dart:_http/http_impl.dart': <source not available>" from?

Comment: new window from where? From your IDE?

Comment: i identify the error . i add this line in    
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' dependencies and  "multiDexEnabled true" in defaultConfig line and this all error stated how to solve this?

Comment: I don't know how build.gradle would be related to the error message from your question, but if you identified it you might be able to fix it or track it down. I don't think I can help you here.